# Configure float with decimal in sql or force string to show decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQl with a column in float type  , this table is used to send values to a one fiscal printer,

```
   code        name              price
   ----------------------------------
    34             cUP               2,5
    36             BOOK              2
    37             COMET             1,2
    38             TOY               1
```

IS posible configure SQl to show 1,00  o 2,00 when the value have not cents.
When i send to the printer i use this line :

```
 string preco = vercup.Rows[i]["unitario"].ToString();
```

how can i force to show 1,00 when the values comes 1.

Comment: Yes, use either the `decimal` or `money` data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you store the data isn't related to how the data is presented.  yes, when you present the data you can force it to display two decimals.

```
select convert(decimal(9,2), price) from table
```

That's just 1 possible solution.

Comment: solved :             preco =   string.Format ("{0:0.00}", vercup.Rows[i]["unitario"]);